# Multi-column div with image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying style a 2-col div with an image the width of one column in the first column, using the CSS3 property column-count. For browsers that CAN handle CSS3, it should look like this:

```
img col
col col
col col
col col
```

However, for browsers that cannot read the CSS, instead of having the image stuck in the top left with the text starting on the next line, I want it floating, like this:

```
img texttextte
xttexttexttext
texttetexttext
```

Currently, I have this for the image in question, which lays out exactly what I want for browsers that CAN'T support CSS3:

```
display: inline;
float: left;
-webkit-column-span: in-column;
-moz-column-span: in-column;
```

But for browsers that can support it, it appears like this, with the image taking up a column all to itself:

```
img col col
    col col
    col col
    col col
```

...which is not what I want at all. How do I get that image to float, with or without columns?

---

EDIT:

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <h2>Title here</h2>
    <img src="/static/images/img01.jpg" width="200" height="152" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Nam porttitor urna sit amet est pulvinar congue. Integer 
    lacinia dictum enim, non molestie turpis volutpat et. Praesent 
    pretium accumsan sapien, porttitor rhoncus augue porta ac. 
    Quisque fermentum enim quis magna condimentum a lobortis urna 
    accumsan. Integer viverra tristique turpis, sed fermentum 
    lorem hendrerit vitae.</p>
</div>
```

Here is the not-quite-working CSS so far:

```
#content {
    width: 600px;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 18px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 18px;
}
#content img {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    -webkit-column-span: in-column;
    -moz-column-span: in-column;
}
```

I feel like a floating, inline image shouldn't behave that way in a column.

Comment: Your `column-span` declarations [appear to be invalid](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#column-span), or [non-standard](http://kmsm.ca/2010/an-almost-complete-guide-to-css3-multi-column-layouts/).

Comment: @David Thomas - Thank you. That solved it. Just had to change

    -webkit-column-span
    -moz-column-span

to

    column-span

Answer (score 0):

You could try this...

```
<img src="/static/images/img01.jpg" width="200" height="152" style="float: left;"/>
```

...as an inline style (better still as a class in an external style sheet) or with the good old align attribute ...

```
<img align="left" src="/static/images/img01.jpg" width="200" height="152" />
```

...I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the image in the p tag. Your size for the columns and the image you have preset so you're good. I've done this no problem, the only thing you can't do is have the image span multiple columns.